# Mysql updating data using name generator with ruby

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We have a table that has 13m rows,It's name and surname fields are nil by default, when we are trying to push some data, it stops running after 1.2m query. We looped with 10k row each because of ram issue.

The algorithm is,

```
$i = 0;
until $i > 13000  do
    b = Tahsil.where("NO < ?",(10000*($i+1))).offset(10000*$i)
    b.each do |a|
      a.name = Generator('name')
      a.surname = Generator('surname')
      a.save
    end

    $i += 1
end
```

Comment: The algorithm stops after 1.2m query

Comment: I'd like to learn why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails has some methods build in that you might want to use:

```
Tahsil.find_each do |tahsil|
  tahsil.update(name: Generator('name'), surname: Generator('surname'))
end
```

[`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) iterates through all records in batches (with a default batch size of 1000). [`update`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update) updates a record.

Comment: That is looks helpful,